# Getting bad max and min values from list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I used `split` to remove whitespaces and turn string into list and using built in function I tried to find the max and min values of the list but I gave incorrect ans also I want ans in formate " x y "where x and y are max and min respectively.
When I print list it consist of ' ' every elements of list
Thanks in Advance.

My code:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    numbers = numbers.split()
    numbers = list(numbers)
    return max(numbers),min(numbers)


print high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/1h7NXs USING built in max min

Answer (score 4):

`split` returns strings, and you don't convert the strings to actual numbers. When comparing strings, the meaning of the comparison is different than when comparing numbers:

```
>>> '2' > '10'
True
```

So you need to change your function to something like this:

```
In [1]: def high_and_low(s):
   ...:     numbers = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
   ...:     return max(numbers), min(numbers)
   ...: 

In [2]: high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
Out[2]: (542, -214)
```

Answer (score 2):

min and max take a key so if you don't actually want ints returned you can use `key=int` so you compare as integers and not strings which is what you are currently doing:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    numbers = numbers.split()
    return max(numbers,key=int),min(numbers,key=int)
```

Or use `map` to cast the strings to int after splitting if you want ints:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
   numbers = map(int,numbers.split())
   return max(numbers,key=int),min(numbers,key=int)
```

numbers is already a list after splitting so  using `numbers = list(numbers)` is redundant.

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> sequence objects may be compared to other objects with the same sequence type. The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted

So for min you only get the correct answer `-214` because -2 is < -6 and -3, once you add `-1` or anything starting with -1 then you would again see incorrect output.

For the max   you get `'6'` because `"6"` is greater than the first char of any other substring.

Comment: Thanks buddy its worked so we have to specify the key like here int  or float as per its content

Comment: @user182766, yes. Unless you have ints then you need to cast the strings to float or int, python will compare strings character by character so "2" > "12" because "2" is greater than "1".

Comment: try adding `-123` to your string and it won't give you the correct min